# command batch file curl upload

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl, cmd, command

I have to upload files using curl. 
I can upload single or multiple file using file name, but i want to uplaod all files in a filder with *.csv mask. How i can upload it. as i read on one of the post saying, curl doesn't support wildcards.

```
ForFiles /m *.csv /c "cmd /c curl.exe -u "username:passowrd" -ssl --cacert "cacert.pem" -F "pfile=@stasticsData.csv" -F "profileKey=001" https://somewebsite.com/api/api-upload.php >> output.txt
```

If i can use same ForFiles with following, I can get file name in @file

```
ForFiles /m *.csv /c "cmd /c echo @file
```

I tried combining, it deson't work, plz help

```
ForFiles /m *.csv /c "cmd /c curl.exe -u "username:passowrd" -ssl --cacert "cacert.pem" -F "pfile=@file" -F "profileKey=001" https://somewebsite.com/api/api-upload.php >> output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I got answer:

```
for %%f in (*.csv) do (
  curl.exe -u "username:password" -ssl --cacert "cacert.pem" -F "pfile=@%%f" -F "profileKey=001" https://somewebsite.com/api/api-upload.php >> output.txt
)
```

Answer (score 0):

see here, maybe will help,
https://support.precisionlender.com/hc/en-us/articles/206935207-Using-a-batch-file-to-automate-uploads-with-cURL

He is using '-H' for header ,like if you need add cookies..
and '-F' for the file specification.